# How to pass in conditional values to query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB. I am having trouble writing filter logic for the following. Would you be so kind to help me out. =>

If **isNightParty:true**, check in DB for **isNightParty Allowed:true** and return all documents else **Do Not Check**

Here is my code:

```js
    router.get("/hotelList", (req,res) =>{
      const {date, boys, girls, isNightParty} = req.body
      businessUser.find(
      {
        $and:[
        {isBlockedOn:{$ne:date}},
        //{girlsWithBoys:isGirlsWithBoys},
        {"isNightPartyAllowed":{$exists:true}}
      }
        ).then((toListHotels)=>{
        return (res.status(200).json(toListHotels))  
      })
      .catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err)
        })
    
    })
```

My DB structure is as follows:

```json
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6182603cce3b3b92991fee96"
    },
    "hotelName": "Hotel",
    "email": "hotel1@hotel.com",
    "password": "$2a$12$RXr2xTbnGP2ASUTqP2ptQOtS36QOr0.uq/OHTuIRLigYUM..T3lb6",
    "location": "url",
    "address": "address",
    "isNightPartyAllowed": true,
    "girlsWithBoys": true,
    "roomSmallData": {
      "smallPrice": "1000",
      "smallPic": "url",
      "smallCapacity": {
        "$numberInt": "5"
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6182603cce3b3b92991fee97"
      }
    },
    "roomMediumData": {
      "mediumPrice": "2000",
      "mediumPic": "url",
      "mediumCapacity": {
        "$numberInt": "7"
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6182603cce3b3b92991fee98"
      }
    },
    "roomLargeData": {
      "largePrice": "3000",
      "largePic": "url",
      "largeCapacity": {
        "$numberInt": "10"
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6182603cce3b3b92991fee99"
      }
    },
    "__v": {
      "$numberInt": "0"
    },
    "isBlockedOn": [
      "Fri Nov 05 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `$or` to cater the 2 conditions:

1. input `isNightParty` is null
2. `isNightPartyAllowed` is true
   either case should allow the documents to be returned

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          // put your parameter <isNightParty> here
          {
            $eq: [
              null,
              <isNightParty>
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                "$ifNull": [
                  "$isNightPartyAllowed",
                  false
                ]
              },
              true
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OmTcjjJyAPi) for your reference.